# Mount a windows host directory in compose file version 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I trying to upgrade docker-compose.yml from version 1 to version 3.

Main question about

```
volumes_from: To share a volume between services, 
define it using the top-level volumes option and 
reference it from each service that shares it using the 
service-level volumes option.
```

Simplest example:

version "1"

```
data:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - ./pg_hba.conf/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf

postgres:
  restart: always
  image:  postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

If I have understood correctly, should be converted to

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - appn

  networks:
    appn:

  volumes:
    db-data:?
```

Question: How now in **top-level volumes option** i can set **relative path** to **folder** "example_folder" from **windows host** to **"db-data"** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, you might consider *not* using `volumes_from`.

As mentioned in this [docker 1.13 issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30441#issuecomment-275113225) by [Sebastiaan van Stijn (thaJeztah)](https://github.com/thaJeztah):

> The `volumes_from` is basically a "lazy" way to copy volume definitions from one container to another, so;
>
> ```
> docker run -d --name one -v myvolume:/foo image-one
>
> docker run -d --volumes-from=one image-two
> ```
>
> Is the same as running;
>
> ```
> docker run -d --name one -v myvolume:/foo image-one
> docker run -d --name two -v myvolume:/foo image-two
> ```
>
> If you are deploying to AWS you should not use bind-mounts, but use named `volumes` instead (as in my example above), for example;
>
> ```
> version: "3.0"
>
> services:
>   db:
>     image: nginx
>     volumes:
>       - uploads-data:/usr/share/nginx/html/uploads/
>
> volumes:
>   uploads-data:
> ```
>
> Which you can run with docker-compose;
>
> ```
> docker-compose up -d
> Creating network "foo_default" with the default driver
> Creating volume "foo_uploads-data" with default driver
> Creating foo_db_1
> ```

Basically, it is not available in docker compose version 3:

> There's a couple of reasons `volumes_from` is not ported to the compose-file "3";
>
> - In a swarm, there is no guarantee that the "`from`" container is running on the same node. Using `volumes_from` would not lead to the expected result.
>     This is especially the case with bind-mounts, which, in a swarm, have to exist on the host (are not automatically created)
> - There is still a "race" condition (as described earlier)
> - The "data" container has to use exactly the right paths for volumes as the "app" container that uses the volumes (i.e. if the "app" uses the volume in `/some/path/in/container`, then the data container also has to have the volume at `/some/path/in/container`). There are many cases where the volume may be shared by multiple services, and those may be consuming the volume in different paths.

---

But also, as mentioned in [issue 19990](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19990#issuecomment-258587160):

> The "regular" volume you're describing is a **bind-mount, *not* a volume**; you specify a path from the host, and it's mounted in the container. No data is copied from the container to that path, because the files from the host are used.
>
> For a volume, you're asking docker to create a volume (persistent storage) to store data, and copy the data from the container to that volume.
>
> Volumes are managed by docker (or through a plugin) and the storage path (or mechanism) is an implementation detail, as all you're asking is a storage, that's managed.

For your question, you would need to define a docker volume container and copy your host content in it:

```
services:
  data:
    image: "nginx:alpine"
    volumes:
      - ./pg_hba.conf/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: Nice answer with useful links. thaJeztah`s posts makes more sense then whole (Compose file reference) page. Also "Bind-mounts are not volumes (but use the same flag, which can be confusing from a naming perspective)." makes it clear for me.